# Graphing Parabolas ( finding area)

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, graphing-functions

Find the area of the triangle formed by the origin and the points of intersection of parabolas $y=−3x^2+20$ and $y=x^2−16$.

I tried graphing it. I could figure out what it meant when it's said formed by the origin. Please help.

Could someone also please post a picture of the two graphs using online because I don't know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: So what traingle do you mean? From which to whick point

Comment: @JanEerland The triangle formed by the origin and two intersection points.

Comment: from the origin connected to the points of intersection

Comment: You need to first solve for the coordinates of the two intersection points, and then calculate the area of the triangle

Comment: Recall that the origin is the point (0,0). The other two points are the intersections, hence a triangle can be made.

Answer (score 2):

Find solutions to $$\begin{cases}
y=-3x^2+20\\
y=x^2-16
\end{cases}$$

$$-3x^2+20=x^2-16$$
$$36=4x^2$$
$$9=x^2$$
$$x=\pm 3\implies y=9-16=-7$$

So the solutions are $(3,-7)$ and $(-3,-7)$. The area is equal to

$$S=\frac{6\cdot 7}{2}=21$$

Comment: why are they equal to each other (the equations)?

Comment: @Daniel That's how you solve for the intersection points. At the intersection points, $y$ values from two curves are equal.

Comment: @Daniel we make the system of equations to find their intersection (these two points), the first step I make is to compare $-3x^2+20$ to $x^2-16$ as they are both equal to $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate the answer of kamilo9875.

[image]

In red the parabola $ y=20-3x^2$ in blue $y=x^2-16$, The triangle is $AOB$ and  $A=(-3,-7)$, so the area is $3\times 7=21$.